# Angular + Firebase firestore - inner subscription to document returns two values on initial subscribe

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire as my API for firebase on Angular 11+.

The domain of my app are real-time auctions

What I'd like to do ideally is read all documents and then subscribe to each one for changes.

My troubles currently are the number of reads I'm making on firestore.

My collection read will yield N reads. But subscribing to each document will yield additional read making it by default 2N reads which seems to be inevitable.

But I guess it's better than to leave a subscription on the collection and receiving N reads each time something from the collection is updated.

So with the sample code below, I make a query to collection and then another query to the document. Simplified just for repro.

```
  this.store.collection("users").valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    concatMap(() => this.store.doc("user/1").valueChanges())
  )
  .subscribe(console.log(user));
```

However, Inner observable will emit 2 times.

Once with `added` and one with `modified` snapshot change type.

So my question is:

Why does my inner observable emit two times in a row on initial subscribe when it seems to me like it should emit only once.

If both of those emits count as reads on firestore this would yield 3N reads.

By my testing on firestore monitoring page, it seems to be the case since on the 400 document page I had about 1200 reads recorded on firestore and counted in pricing.

1. What am I doing wrong in sample code potentially?
2. Does anyone have advice on how should I retrieve data more
   efficiently with less reads?
3. Should I switch to RTDB which seems to have more generous offer of
   10GB data output which could be better for my reads volume?

Edit:

So I just tested with angularfire API for firebase RTDB.

Sample code like above would make inner observable emit just 1 value as expected and 1 per item change. Which is expected.

Still not clear to me exactly why firestore implementation would emit 2 values which both count as read and take away on pricing.

End code would look something like this:

```
this.db.list<AuctionItem>(`auctions/1/items`)
.valueChanges()
.pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(items => this.itemsToRender = items),
  mergeMap(items => [...items]),
  mergeMap((item: AuctionItem) => this.db.object(`auctions/1/items/${item.id}`).valueChanges() as Observable<AuctionItem>),
)
.subscribe(change => {
  // do work when item updates
})
```

Still not sure why firestore isn't working for me as expected. Thinking about having partial firestore + RTDB for optimal usage since reads are going high for me on firestore even with 50k free.

Comment: There is definitely room for optimization with Firestore. Typically you would (almost) never want to read all documents of a collection. Answer me this: 1: why do you want to read all documents? 2: why do you want to listen for changes?
There are probably better ways to achieve your aim.

Comment: I'm not reading all documents but for the sake of simplicity. I'm actually having virtual scroll and pagination.

I wish to read documents because I need to know which items I have in the auction and render them.

I need to listen to changes because it's a real-time auction application and I'm updating bids and what not as documents change over time with user activity while user is on the page 

If I'm not listening individual item but instead subscribe only to pages I'd be getting PAGE_SIZE documents retrieved every time any item in that page is updated. Which is not optimal also.

Comment: My auction details page consists of some auction details and just endless scrollable page of auction items with their current bid prices.

My model is:

Collection of auctions where each auction document has collection of items. As users bid I just update items current bid value.. which should reflect to UI if user is currently observing that item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would do in your situation:

1. Do a onSnapshot() query, (the first read operation)
   --> But limit results to 10 or 20. (cheap!)
2. On user scroll -> load more. ([Firestore pagination ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors))
3. When a document change --> update the displayed data

When listening for changes, you're only charged again for the documents that *did change*, not the ones you already queried that didn't get any updates.

For more details on pricing for listeners, watch [this video (especially at 3:16)](https://youtu.be/3aoxOtMM2rc?t=196)

Comment: Yeah implemented it like that. One thing I observed is that the man in the video said you don't get charged for the whole array but only the items that come back. However, when I retrieve snapshot metadata it says all items in array are not from cache. The fromCache flag is always false. Makes me wonder.

Comment: I now have expected amount of reads on the auction page 400 when browsing on computer. However, when I browse on my phone and scroll one 400 item auction I get about 5k reads instead of 400. I don't have any logic implemented for mobile phone except flexbox for responsive UI.

Don't frankly get it at the moment. Also not sure how to debug it

Comment: So I solved my issues, I'll mark this as the correct answer. But I'd like to point out to future readers to make sure they have their service scopes in check too.